Want to push to my github repository from my github actions workflow
I have a django authentication application, I am currently creating a ci/cd for it so when any change is pushed to my remote github repo it would be reflected on the live server
I created a simple file in the root dir called init.py which only does one thing --> hold the current version of the application. so for instance at the beginning its 1.0.0 and with changes it would updated to 1.0.1 or 1.1.0 etc... , just to keep track of the updates
init.py
__version__ = "1.0.0"

now I created github actions workflow that would do the next, when a push request is made it would check the commit message if he commit message contains the word "patch" the workflow would change the version in the init.py by adding one to the patch slot 1.0.0 --> 1.0.1, if the message contains the word "minor" 1.0.0 --> 1.1.0
now I want the workflow which made changes to the init.py file to push this change to my github repository, like literally any normal push request
but I am getting this error
remote: Permission to TheHunter597/djangoAuthApp.git denied to github-actions[bot].
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/TheHunter597/djangoAuthApp.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

I have tried so many things here is some
1- created PAS (personal access token) (I have given this PAS every permission possible I checked all the boxes available) and tried to use it ( here the personal access token is stored inside the environment variable called GH_PAT )
      - name: update git repo
        continue-on-error: true
        env:
          GH_PAT: ${{ secrets.GH_PAT }}
        run: |
          git config --global user.email "thehunter597777@gmail.com"
          git config --global user.name "TheHunter597"
          git remote set-url origin https://x-access-token:${GH_PAT}@github.com/TheHunter597/djangoAuthApp.git
          git add .
          git commit -m "Bump version to ${{ steps.get_required_version.outputs.version }} [skip ci]"
          git push

2- tried to login using username and PAS
      - name: update git repo 5
        continue-on-error: true
        env:
          GH_PAT: ${{ secrets.GH_PAT }}
        run: |
          git config --global user.email "thehunter597777@gmail.com"
          git config --global user.name "TheHunter597"
          git remote set-url origin https://TheHunter597:$GH_PAT@github.com/TheHunter597/djangoAuthApp.git
          git push

3- tried to login using username and password
      - name: update git repo 7
        continue-on-error: true
        env:
          GH_PAT: ${{ secrets.GH_PAT }}
        run: |
          git config --global user.email "thehunter597777@gmail.com"
          git config --global user.name "TheHunter597"
          git remote set-url origin https://TheHunter597:${{secrets.PASSWORD}}@github.com/TheHunter597/djangoAuthApp.git
          git push

4- tried to login to github using gh and GITHUB_TOKEN
      - name: update git repo 8
        env:
          GH_PAT: ${{ secrets.GH_PAT }}
        run: |
          git config --global user.email "thehunter597777@gmail.com"
          git config --global user.name "TheHunter597"
          echo ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} | gh auth login --with-token
          git push

all of them give the same error, here is my latest github actions workflow latest workflow run
please note that all these changes are done on the formatting-tests branch formatting-tests branch
My github actions file
There is absolutely something that I am missing here, thanks for help :)

First of all you don't need to use a PAT token, if you want to push to a repository itself see example below.
The reason why your authentication attempts didn't working as expected is the persist-credentials option of the checkout action. By default it is set to true. If it's true it basically overwrits/ignores all of your authentication configuration.
Here is an example of how to commit and push to your repository without any PAT token.
jobs:
  example:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: write
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with: 
          persist-credentials: false
      - uses: qoomon/actions--setup-git@v1
        # by default this action setup github-actions[bot] as user
        # if you want use a different user you can choose from following user configs
        # with:
          # user: actor       # github actions ${{ context github.actor }} as git user
          # user: committer   # committer from HEAD commit as git user
          # user: gTheHunter597 <thehunter597777@gmail.com>
      - run: |
          date > dummy.txt
          git add dummy.txt
          git commit -m "chore: update dummy"
          git push


I tried your solution but it failed with the same error
Here is the workflow run failed workflow run
but I tried this
- uses: actions/checkout@v4  with: persist-credentials: "false"
and it actually worked
I do not know if I miss used your package but after adding the persist-credentials to false it worked success workflow

Please edit your solution and add - uses: actions/checkout@v4  with: persist-credentials: "false" and I would accept your solution
Thank you :)
